# In Unity, how do you manually set an interactable to an interactor (XR Grab Interactable to XR Socket Interactor)

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to figure out how to manually attach an XR Grab Interactable to a XR Socket Interactor but using `XRBaseInteractor.selectTarget` has the `protected` modifier.

How can you do this via C# in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XR Interaction Manager to help with this!

Both `XRSocketInteractor.StartManualInteraction();` and `XRInteractionManager.ForceSelect();` are now confirmed working in the **XR Interaction Toolkit 1.0.0-pre.5**

Example script for testing:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;

public class XRSocketConnector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public XRSocketInteractor socket;
    public XRBaseInteractable interactable;
    public XRInteractionManager interactionManager;

    void Start()
    {
        // Both of these work in 1.0.0-pre.5
        socket.StartManualInteraction(interactable);
        // interactionManager.ForceSelect(socket, interactable);
    }
}
```